# Java polymorphism and overloading different data types

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism, overriding

I could not understand Java's polymorphism and overloading logic.

Assuming I have 2 Classes, A and B.
B extends A.
B also have a overloading method, which differ in the data type input.

In the code below, in the last class we execute the same method but the prints are completely different. I would appreciate if give me a reference to that idea because I couldn't under that case.
Why would (in the code) number 1 and 2 or 3 and 4 would be different?

What is the logic?
is ab not AAA nor BBB? 
is it due to its both?

Thanks

```
public class AAA {
     private int _val;
     public AAA() {_val=1};
     public AAA(int val) {_val=val;}
     public int getVal(){return _val};
}

public class BBB extends AAA {
     private String _st;
     public BBB (){_st="bbb";}
     public BBB(String st, int val){
         super(val);
         _st=st;
     }
     public String getSt(){return _st;} 

     public boolean equals (Object other) {
         System.out.print("Object ");
         if (other instanceof BBB)
         return (_st.equals(((BBB)other)._st) &&
         (getVal()==((BBB)other).getVal()));
         return false;
     }
     public boolean equals (AAA other) {
         System.out.print("AAA ");
         if (other instanceof BBB)
         return (_st.equals(((BBB)other)._st) &&
         (getVal()==((BBB)other).getVal()));
         return false;
     }
     public boolean equals (BBB other) {
         System.out.print("BBB ");
         return (_st.equals(other._st)) &&
         (getVal()== other.getVal());
     }
}

public class Driver {
     public static void main (String [] args) {
         AAA a1 = new AAA(5);
         AAA ab = new BBB();
         BBB b1 = new BBB();

         if (b1.equals(a1)) System.out.println(1); 
         if (ab1.equals(a1)) System.out.println(2);  

         if (b1.equals(b1)) System.out.println(3); 
         if (ab.equals(ab)) System.out.println(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: We call polymorphysm the case when the same method (same name, same parameters) called on objects of different classes leads to different results. If you want to analyze / research how it works, you need at least one method that is defined in both classes. In your code you have no such method. For instance, define method `getSt()` also in the AAA class, but use different implementation. Then call it on your objects `a1`, `ab` and `b1`.

Comment: Hi @mentallurg I appreciate your answer, but what I mean is that ab1.equals and b.equals directs me differently and I cannot understand why. Thanks

Comment: `equals(Object)` is in Object. So `if (ab.equals(a1)) System.out.println(2);` would use `equals(Object)` in BBB.

Comment: @VitalyChait: Your usage of `equals` has nothing to do with polymorphism. You just implemented new methods in the class BBB. They don't exist in the class AAA. Change your question. Remove the word "polymorphism" and tell us more precisely what is your question, what exactly is not clear.

Comment: @mentallurg thanks for clarifications but it is related to my question.

What I mean is that 
ab.equals
and
b.equals 

Would both implement a method from B class but ab.equals always load object method and b.equals will load the correct method.

so b.equals(b) and ab.equals(b) will not be implemented the same way, why does that happen?

Comment: @VitalyChait: 1) "so b.equals(b) and ab.equals(b) will not be implemented the same way" - this is not true. If you call `b1.equals(b1)` and `ab.equals(b1)`, they will of course give *the same* result. But in your example above you have no test case for `b1.equals(b1)`. Out of 9 possible combinations you have tested only 4.

Comment: @VitalyChait: "ab.equals always load object method" - this is not true, because `ab = new BBB();` and `ab` will use `equals` method from `BBB`, not from `Object`. May be you mean `a1`? In `a1` you have *not* overridden `euquals`, that's why a1 will use `equals` from `Object`.

Comment: @VitalyChait: Please compare also the code that you published here with the code that your are using currnetly in your PC. May be you work with other code, for instance, you refer in your comment `a` and `b`, but in your example above there are no such variables. Instead there are `a1` and `b1`.